# Nest JS ConfigService cannot able to read the .env file after fresh clone

Tags: node.js, nestjs, dotenv

On my old pc, let's call it PC-1, I have a nest js backend application and environmental files are working properly when I run **npm run start:dev**. I'm using nest js built-in ConfigService/ConfigModule to read the environtmental variables from .env file. However, when I transfer to other new pc(PC-2) and clone the files, then the below error exist.

> MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

Obviously, my .env files is not read. That is why it returns undefined.

Alternatively when i install dotenv and call the **config** function, then it will work smoothly. But Im wondering on my previous computer  I didn't install dotenv package and it works smootly because under the hood, Nest JS ConfigService/ConfigModule uses dotenv.

Please help!

Comment: I'm using the same built-in module just like how the docs shows with no worries. If you could make some repo reproducing this, would be great.

Comment: Hi Michael. Yes on my old pc its working properly without any issues. But when i clone it to other pc then the error occurs...